# How to find rectangle contours in an image with text overlapping on the edges

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find the rectangles in an image. The rectangles can have text as shown in the following sample image.

[image: sample image]

with findContours and cv2.approxPolyDP, i'm able to detect only a subset of rectanlges(highlighted in green) and having difficulties finding the rectangles with text crossing the boundaries.

[image]

Is there a better mechanism to find all the rectangles. (tried increasing the epsilon parameter for the approxPolyDP, but it looks a hack to me)

attached is the code snippet i have

```
img = cv2.imread(fname)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,0)


image,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if len(approx)==4:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        #print x, y, w, h
        carea = cv2.contourArea(cnt, True)
        # if carea is less than 0, the contour is a duplicate - counting both inner and outer edge of the rect
        if carea<0:
            continue
        if x==0:
            continue
        print x, y, w, h

        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),5)

cv2.imshow("Original", gray)
cv2.imshow("Contours", img)
```

Comment: Instead of finding directly the rectangles, try finding horizontal and vertical lines, using `HoughTransform()`, then later find out the vertices where these line segments intersect. I think it should generate better results.

Comment: Hi ZdaR, thank you for the response. what mechanisms are available to join the lines returned by Hough Transformation. I'm exploring the option of using 1xM Nx1 kernel for the vertical and hotizontal lines

Comment: There are no off the shelf methods in OpenCV to find the intersection points, it would only return you the line segments, You can later calculate the intersections points, the math is fairly simple.